# how can I set custom background color on a XWPFTableCell?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I hope someone can help with this.

Im trying to generate docx document using apache poi which I am able to but now I am having a problem on how can I set background color in a table column or cell?

I'm trying to achieve something like this. [image: here]

This is what I had so far.[image: here]

Below is my code.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
   XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
   XWPFTable table = doc.createTable(3, 4);
   fillHeader(table);
   mergeCellsHorizontally(table, 0, 0, 1);
   mergeCellsVertically(table, 2, 0, 1);
   mergeCellsVertically(table, 3, 0, 1);
}

private static void fillHeader(XWPFTable table) {
    XWPFTableRow row = table.getRow(0);
    row.getCell(0).setText("Column 1");
    row.getCell(2).setText("Column 2");
    row.getCell(3).setText("Column 3");
    XWPFTableRow row1 = table.getRow(1);
    row1.getCell(0).setText("Col 1 Row 1");
    row1.getCell(1).setText("Col 2 Row 1");
}

private static void mergeCellsHorizontally(XWPFTable table, int row, int 
  fromCol, int toCol) {
   for (int cellIndex = fromCol; cellIndex <= toCol; cellIndex++) {
      XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(row).getCell(cellIndex);
      if (cellIndex == fromCol) {ue
        cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewHMerge().setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
      } else {
        cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewHMerge().setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
      }
  }
 }

 private static void mergeCellsVertically(XWPFTable table, int col, int 
  fromRow, int toRow) {
   for (int rowIndex = fromRow; rowIndex <= toRow; rowIndex++) {
      XWPFTableCell cell = table.getRow(rowIndex).getCell(col);
      if (rowIndex == fromRow) {
        cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewVMerge().setVal(STMerge.RESTART);
      } else {
        cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewVMerge().setVal(STMerge.CONTINUE);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What about [XWPFTableCell.setColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#setColor%28java.lang.String%29)? Have you tried?

Comment: Nice it work now. I initially thought that method was used for changing the font color.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Set background color for a cell, do like below :

```
cell.getCTTc().addNewTcPr().addNewShd().setFill("cccccc");
```

the color should use hex like `cccccc`.